# HTML table from shortcode with multiple parameters

Tags: php, functions, html, table

I've struck this problem, and I just can't solve it. I've come a long way with all the maths behind the table and the table being put out as a result of a function behind the shortcode. Then I also managed to make the table variable by using the attributes assigned to a shortcode. But what would complete my function is the ability to pass several inputs to the same shortcode and those inputs forming a nice table. I've tried using several shortcodes, but better would be if everything could be fit into one shortcode. It's probably a little vague now, let me clear things up by supplying some code.

```
function test( $atts ) {

// Attributes
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'investment' => '1',
        'coinamount' => '0.5',
        'coin' => 'BTC',
        'currency' => 'EUR',
    ),
    $atts,
    'investment'
);

//Declaring all my variables
$coinworth = get_coin_worth($atts['coin'], $atts['currency']);
$currencyworth = get_currency_worth($atts['coin'], $atts['currency']);
$coinname = get_coin_name($atts['coin']);
$currencyname = get_currency_name($atts['currency']);
$investment = $atts['investment'];
$coinamount = $atts['coinamount'];
$portfolioworth = $coinamount*$coinworth;
$result = $portfolioworth - $investment;
$result = number_format((float)$result, 2, '.', '');

//Creating the table 
$table = <<<EOD
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Uw Portfolio</h1>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Invested Currency</th>
                <th>Investment Worth</th>
                <th>Coin amount</th>
                <th>Recent Portfolioworth</th>
                <th>Result</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>$currencyname</td>
                <td>$investment</td>
                <td>$coinamount</td>
                <td>$coinworth</td>
                <td $style$result</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
EOD; 
return $table;
}
```

As you can see, it's a pretty big function, take some time to understand it. Now, I've seen [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17187/shortcodes-html-tables-and-multiple-rows), but as you see I have multiple data inputs for every row and I just can't grasp how to combine them all the way i'm doing right now.

Anyone any idea? You will be helping me loads!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example of how you can achive what you are after:

You can use it like this :

> [itable
>   data="inv;coin;coinamount;currency#inv;coin;coinamount;currency"]

```
function itable_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'data' => 'none',
    ), $atts ) );

    $data = explode('#',$data);

    $output = "";

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $output .= '<tr>';
        $in_value = explode(';',$value);

        // next step is check if exist or is the type you want like integer or string
        $investment  = $in_value[0];
        $coin        = $in_value[1];
        $coinamount  = $in_value[2];
        $currency    = $in_value[3];

        //Declaring all my variables
        $coinworth      = get_coin_worth($coin, $currency);
        $currencyworth  = get_currency_worth($coin,$currency);
        $coinname       = get_coin_name($coin);
        $currencyname   = get_currency_name($currency);


        $portfolioworth = $coinamount*$coinworth;
        $result = $portfolioworth - $investment;
        $result = number_format((float)$result, 2, '.', '');

        $output .= '<td>'.$currencyname.'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$investment.'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$coinamount.'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$coinworth.'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$result.'</td>';
        $output .= '</tr>';
    }
//Creating the table 
$table = <<<EOD
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Uw Portfolio</h1>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Invested Currency</th>
                <th>Investment Worth</th>
                <th>Coin amount</th>
                <th>Recent Portfolioworth</th>
                <th>Result</th>
            </tr>
            $output
        </table>
EOD;
    return $table;

}

function itable_shortcodes_init() {
    add_shortcode('itable', 'itable_shortcode');
}

add_action('init', 'itable_shortcodes_init');
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm. Thank you so much. This was just the thing I couldn't get done :)